# Call a function from another nested controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My view is using my `ProjectController`:

```
<tbody ng-controller="ProjectController">
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <td class="col-md-3">{{ task.id}}</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ task.taskType.name }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ task.description }}</td>
        <td><div ng-bind-html="callMethodFromTaskController(task)"></div></td>
        <td><a href="#/tasks/{{ task.id }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Abrir</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I call `callMethodFromTaskController`, a function that is inside `TaskController` to style the information?

Comment: You cannot, controllers are there to support the view and interdependence is not supported unless the form a parent-child hierarchy using `scope`. You need to move the common function to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H-i, there's a couple of ways to do this.

The simplest thing that could possibly work is to put callMethodFromTaskController()'s output on task.methodOutput, then put methodOutput in a div:  `<div ng-bind-html="task.methodOutput"></div>`

There's probably a reason for calling this at runtime.  Instead of putting the function on the controller, put the function on `task` instead.  That's already in scope:

`<div ng-bind-html="task.callMethodFromTaskController()"></div>`

I think you'll find that more compatible with Angular thinking in the long run.

If *that* doesn't work.  Then you're probably making a special control.  In that case, consider using a 'directive' (simpler and more fun than it sounds).

In which case, you'd pass task to the directive, like this:

```
<tbody ng-controller="ProjectController" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <taskDirective task="task">
</tbody>
```

You can learn more about directives [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals).

Comment: Directives did the job!

Comment: Nice!  Glad I could help :-)